# SVG layer not rescale width map layer

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

Im using leaflet, which have map layer and svg layer.But when im zooming, the svg layer not scale with the map layer size. Which make the svg layer size wrong, and not display my svg content

this is my code

```
MapLeaflet.prototype.init = function (map) {
  let $$ = this;
  $$.dom = map;
  this.map = L.map(map).setView([-6.175239, 106.827204], 13);
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo($$.map);

  this.svg = d3.select($$.map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg")
    .attr('style', 'display: flex; flex: 1 1 auto; min-height: 100vh; min-width: 100vw; position: relative; flex-grow: 1')
    .append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i should not manualy add the SVG layer. Leaflet have its own function for adding svg layer

this is my final code

```
MapLeaflet.prototype.init = function (map) {
  let $$ = this;
  $$.dom = map;
  this.map = L.map(map).setView([-6.175239, 106.827204], 13);
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo($$.map);

  var svgLayer = L.svg();
  svgLayer.addTo(this.map);
  this.svg = d3.select('svg g');
}
```